# Behaviour of Bubbling and Capturing Phase

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling, event-capturing

Could somebody please explain the bubbling and capturing phase with this code according to output of the 4 cases in code , on clicking div2 and div1

http://jsfiddle.net/JuKmM/9/

code:

```
function doSomething2(){
 console.log("div 1 clicked");
}

var element1=document.getElementById('div_1');
var element2=document.getElementById('div_2');

element1.addEventListener('click',doSomething2,false);
element2.addEventListener('click',doSomething,true);

//element1.addEventListener('click',doSomething2,false);
//element2.addEventListener('click',doSomething,false);

//element1.addEventListener('click',doSomething2,true);
//element2.addEventListener('click',doSomething,true);

//element1.addEventListener('click',doSomething2,true);
//element2.addEventListener('click',doSomething,false);

function doSomething(){
console.log("div2 clicked");
}
```

Comment: It would help if you would explain what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

From [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

> **useCapture** *Optional*
>
> > If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener designated to use capture. See DOM Level 3 Events for a detailed explanation. If not specified, useCapture defaults to false.

You're setting up the handler for "div_1" such that it does *not* use capture, and the handler for "div_2" such that it *does*, though since it's got no children that doesn't matter much.  Thus:

- A click on the blue part ("div_1") triggers only the handler on that element.
- A click on the red part ("div_2") triggers the handler for that element. The event then bubbles up the DOM to "div_1", and that handler is triggered.